# How does protobuf judge if a value belongs to an optional field, or another object?

Tags: linux, object, protocol-buffers, encode, delimiter

For example, if I define a photo like this:

```
$cat 30.proto
message hello
{
    required int32 f1=1;
    required int32 f2=2;
    optional int32 f3=3;
}
```

Then I would double if protobuf can handle things like this:

1. I declare 3 objects, each don't have `f3` field.
2. Write to output
3. Then, in reader side, how does reader know that these 6 values should belong to 3 objects(each 2 fields), or belong to 2 objects(each 3 fields)?

In another word, how does the "require"/"optional" reflected inside encoded bytes? If not reflected in the byte stream, then how does protobuf determine the start of a new offset? We know protobuf don't have "delimiter" bits.

I had a simple quick test on this:

```
$cat 30.cpp
#include "30.pb.h"
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    fstream f("./log30.data",ios::binary|ios::out);
    hello p1,p2,p3,p4,p5;
    p1.set_f1(1);
    p1.set_f2(2);
    p2.set_f1(3);
    p2.set_f2(4);
    p3.set_f1(5);
    p3.set_f2(6);
    p1.SerializeToOstream(&f);
    p2.SerializeToOstream(&f);
    p3.SerializeToOstream(&f);

    p4.set_f1(7);
    p4.set_f2(8);
    p4.set_f3(9);
    p5.set_f1(0xa);
    p5.set_f2(0xb);
    p5.set_f3(0xc);
    p4.SerializeToOstream(&f);
    p5.SerializeToOstream(&f);
    return 0;
}

$g++ 30.cpp 30.pb.cc -lprotobuf && ./a.out && xxd log30.data
00000000: 0801 1002 0803 1004 0805 1006 0807 1008  ................
00000010: 1809 080a 100b 180c                      ........
```

I just guessed if the byte stream always starts with the smallest tag number, and increases as it dumps the byte stream: when a smaller tag number is met, it thinks that's the start of a new object. Just my humble guess.

Need your explanations!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (3) Then, in reader side, how does reader know that these 6 values
>   should belong to 3 objects(each 2 fields), or belong to 2 objects(each
>   3 fields)?
>
> In another word, how does the "require"/"optional" reflected inside
>   encoded bytes? If not reflected in the byte stream, then how does
>   protobuf determine the start of a new offset? We know protobuf don't
>   have "delimiter" bits.

Protobuf doesn't. It's up to you, the programmer, to split the messages before you feed them to protobuf.

For example, run this program:

```
#include "30.pb.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    fstream f("./log30.data",ios::binary|ios::out);
    hello p1,p2,p3,p4,p5;
    p1.set_f1(1);
    p1.set_f2(2);
    p2.set_f1(3);
    p2.set_f2(4);
    p3.set_f1(5);
    p3.set_f2(6);
    p1.SerializeToOstream(&f);
    p2.SerializeToOstream(&f);
    p3.SerializeToOstream(&f);

    p4.set_f1(7);
    p4.set_f2(8);
    p4.set_f3(9);
    p5.set_f1(0xa);
    p5.set_f2(0xb);
    p5.set_f3(0xc);
    p4.SerializeToOstream(&f);
    p5.SerializeToOstream(&f);
    f.close();
    f.open("./log30.data", ios::binary|ios::in);

    hello hin;
    hin.ParseFromIstream(&f);

    cout << "f1: " << hin.f1() << ", f2: " << hin.f2() << ", f3: " << hin.f3() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

You should see only the values of your last serialized `hello` object, as protobuf reads the *whole* stream and overwrites older values with newer ones.

Answer (score 1):

Form the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#optional)

> As you know, a protocol buffer message is a series of key-value pairs. The binary version of a message just uses the field's number as the key – the name and declared type for each field can only be determined on the decoding end by referencing the message type's definition (i.e. the .proto file).
>
> When a message is encoded, the keys and values are concatenated into a byte stream. When the message is being decoded, the parser needs to be able to skip fields that it doesn't recognize. This way, new fields can be added to a message without breaking old programs that do not know about them. To this end, the "key" for each pair in a wire-format message is actually two values – the field number from your .proto file, plus a wire type that provides just enough information to find the length of the following value.
>
> ...
>
> If a proto2 message definition has repeated elements (without the [packed=true] option), the encoded message has zero or more key-value pairs with the same tag number.

So optional elements could not be placed into output stream. While required must be included. Schema must be known for both serialization and deserialization (in contrast to [Avro where schema must be embedded with data](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/spec.html#Data+Serialization)) so validation of required/optional field happens after deserialization when parser check if all required fields has values.